# iText PDF Filling a form and rolling to a second page if necessary

Tags: itext, pdf-form

I have successfully created an iText form filling app with Java, but am running into a problem, because the dynamic content is not always the same length.

Basically, I am creating an invoice form, and of course, the length of the invoice depends on how many items were ordered.

The form allows for 12 entries, but I cannot figure out what to do if there is more than 12 entries. I have tried adding a page with the same template, but it just adds a blank page at the end and then throws an exception, because it cannot handle the additional information passed.

Any idea how to add more than one page? I am using PdfReader to read in the input file (a .pdf form created with Acrobat). Then I am using the iterator to step through the fields and the Stamper.

I am trying this inside a for loop that is supposed to step through each page, but when it gets to page 2, it errors out, because the PdfReader for that file already exists. Moving the creation of the PdfReader outside the for loop did not help either.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hey well you use pdf AcroForm otherwise you couldn't fill it with iText but AcroForms are static forms, what you want to use are XFAForms a pdf form which is injected with XML, but iText doesn't support XFAForms fully yet.
What you might do is use the coordinates of your first line of products and put a PdfPTable on it which can go over multiple pages, you can specify if a row needs to be complete or not when going to another page, this can be read on chapter 4 in the iText in Action book written by Bruno Lowagie